# Why don't I get a response from my request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, request

I'm trying to make one simple request:

```
ua=UserAgent()
req = requests.get('https://www.casasbahia.com.br/' , headers={'User-Agent':ua.random})
```

I would understand if I received <Response [403] or something like that, but instead, a recive nothing, the code keep runing with no response.

using logging I see:

[image]

I know I could use a timeout to avoid keeping the code running, but I just want to understand why I don't get an response

thanks in advance

Comment: I tried this with a traditional Safari User-Agent and it worked without error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used this API before, but from what I researched on [here](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/) just now, there are sites that can block requests from fake users.

So, for reproducing this example on my PC, I installed *fake_useragent* and *requests* modules on my Python 3.10, and tried to execute your script. It turns out that with my Authentic UserAgent string, the request can be done. When printed on the console, `req.text` shows the entire HTML file received from the request.

But if I try again with a fake user agent, using `ua.random`, it fails. The site was probably developed to detect and reject requests from fake agents (or bots).

Though again, this is just theory. I have no ways to access this site's server files to comprove it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I managed to scrapp with a more appropriate header